Flutter - Autofocus
I have three screens to navigate and second screen should get the autofocus on one TextFormField. Somehow my keyboard didn't want to close when I switched screen. Also tried with FocusNode and when I request focus I can't unfocused the node. Another thing that's strange for me is that the result is different between debug mode and release mode. When I get it working on debug mode it won't take the focus on the TextFormField.
I tried different things and the goal is that in release mode it the TextFormField should always have focus, even on resume and on other screens the keyboard should be hidden again


I have three screens to navigate and second screen should get the
autofocus on one TextFormField.

To achieve this, you can set the autofocus of that TextFormField to a boolean state variable. Now you can add your custom logic to manage the state of this variable, and your TextFormField will get focused accordingly, assuming you are properly managing the state.

Somehow my keyboard didn't want to close when I switched screen.

I unfocus the keyboard when I tap outside the text field because the UI gets quite messy sometimes without this behaviour. It's your decision, but I think this will solve the issue.
FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();


Another thing that's strange for me is that the result is different
between debug mode and release mode.

I never faced this issue with the TextFormField. It would be better if you could share the code. Otherwise, it's hard to say what the issue might be.

Thanks, I tried that already but didn't work. After unfocus the field requested the node again, so I put can Request to false before and when I pop from third screen back I requested the focus again and it finally  worked like expected

Similar issues also in Flutter Web, more info here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59439 More likely to happen in MS Edge than Chrome, but it appears in both. Never on debug mode, may happen in flutter run --release and more often if published on web like i.e. *.codemagic.app or Azure Static Pages (it doesn't matter where, only it is pubished, and browser might handle things in another way).
